# Problem in using sweet alert dialog....show ...Build failed with an exception

Tags: android-studio, android-build

I am creating a app where i need to use customize alert dialog so i am using sweet alert dialog and sync the dependencies into build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
}
```

but when i sync it it

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDebugManifest’.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43
is also present at [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
Suggestion: add ‘tools:replace=“android:icon”’ to element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

and also gradle build stop working can anybody know how to solove this problem…
and
I am using android studio 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Original `pedant` version of the library goes unmaintained, you should to see some other forks that are currently maintained, one option is:

I've made a fork initially for my personal use but then I see that can help to someone else, repo is: https://github.com/eriknyk/sweet-alert-dialog, where it's in Gitpack https://jitpack.io/#eriknyk/sweet-alert-dialog/2.1.3

In short:

1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories

   ```
   repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
   ```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
    dependencies {
             implementation 'com.github.eriknyk:sweet-alert-dialog:2.1.3'
    }
```

It has many fixes and improvements like, dark mode support, and message text alignment, also fixed large message text being cut off.